# readLine() never stops reading

Tags: java, readline

`inFromClientR.readLine()` never stops. any ideas? Am I forgetting something?

Server:

```
/*{ some code:
    send a file with a dataoutputstream to client using a new port(4000) and when transfer is done i want a responce message (e.g. OK) send back to server in the old port(6000)  
}*/
 ServerSocket listenTransferSocket = new ServerSocket(6000);
      Socket connectionTransferSocket = listenTransferSocket.accept();

    BufferedReader inFromClientR =
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionTransferSocket.getInputStream()));

     System.out.println("Client's response to Transfer: " +inFromClientR.readLine());
```

Client:

```
/*{ some code: 
receive the file on port (4000) and then the responce is sent to server using the following commands
}*/
Socket fileTransferSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6000);

 DataOutputStream outToServerR = 
       new DataOutputStream(fileTransferSocket.getOutputStream()); 

        outToServerR.writeBytes("Transfer completed " +'\n');
```

Comment: After writing the "Transfer completed" message, do you `flush()` the stream?

Comment: in client side outToServerR.writeBytes("Transfer completed " +'\n'); never stops.the println after that line never shows

Comment: Why do you append the newline separately from the `String`? What happens if you just do `outToServerR.writeBytes("Transfer completed\n");`?

Comment: How much time did you wait?

Comment: Try using the `writeChars` method.

Comment: i found that the problem is on the code above so i am sorry

Comment: It works for me .. I have put sysout after outToServerR.writeBytes

Comment: its on a wile loop i had above that code that i show here it never stoped.

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader#readLine() tries to fill its buffer with 8192 bytes, regradless of any linefeeds it find meanwhile. Since you have the connection open, the receiving side will wait until 1) you have sent 8192 bytes, or 2) closes the connection.

You would be better off using some other framing mechanism, maybe an ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

```
String line = null;
while ((line = inFromClientR.readLine()) != null) {
   // do sth
}
```